# Spring Security в ответ на регистрациб получаю 403 ошибку

Tags: spring-security

Пробую настроить Spring Security в Spring Boot приложении. На другой стороне работает Angular.
При обращении по адресу

```
POST 
localhost:15001/auth/api/v1/user/register
```

получаю ошибку 403
Перечитал кучу похожих вопросов. Ответ везде один. Ошибка лечится добавлением

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

у меня в конфигурации отключен csrf, это прописано в классе SecurityConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
         securedEnabled = true,
         jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/authentication/api/v1/**",
                        "/auth/api/v1/user/register",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html");
    }


    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/api/v1/user/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

В чем еще может быть проблема?
Ссылка на репозиторий здесь
[проект](https://gitlab.com/gavrilovserg/utppi-sec)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй закомментировать вот эту строчку:

```
configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
```

и снова послать запрос.

У меня почему-то именно это вызывало ошибку